# Friends selection algorithm

Tags: asp.net, algorithm

In a .net project we have a group of 200 people of two types, lets say `x` and `y`, who need to be separated into groups of 7 or 8.

We have a web page where the people write other members they want to be in a group with. Each person builds a list of wanted members.

After this, there should be an algorithm to build the `7-8` member groups considering the peoples ratings, and the following condition: each group has at least 2 people of each type (`x/y`).

I'm pretty sure there must be a well known algorithm similar to this but didn't find one. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: what is the metrics? if there is no perfect solution, how do you evaluate which solution is better then the other?

Comment: Everyone selects friends so the best would be for as many people to be in a group with as many selected friends. And of course considering the types condition.

Comment: so, the metrics should be Sigma(#friends_in_group(u)) for each u in USERS ? [only for legal solutions] ?

Comment: I can't find the article/video I saw a long time ago about how Microsoft selected the best presentation schedule for a number of presenters at a venue where rooms could be very far from one another. You might want to look into generic algorithms to find the best solution. Your sample seems small enough to create all possible solutions and then select the best of those options given your stringent criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem smells [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so I suggest using Artificial Intelligence tools.

A possible approach is [steepest ascent hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing#Variants) [SAHC]
first, we will define our utility function (let it be `u`) as mentioned in the comments to the question. [sum of friends in group for each user]. let's define `u(illegal) = -1` for illegal solution.

next,we define our 'world': `S is the group of all possible solutions`].

for each solution in S we define:

`next(s)={all possibilities moving one person to a different group}`

all we have to do now is run SAHC with random restarts:

```
1. best<- -INFINITY 
2. while there is more time
3. choose a random legal solution
4. NEXT <- next(s)
5. if max{ U(NEXT) } < u(s): //s is the top of the hill
   5.1. if u(s) > best: best <- u(s) //if s is better then the previous result - store it.
   5.2. go to 2. //restart the hill climbing from a different random point.
6. else:
   6.1. s <- max{ NEXT } //climb on the steepest hill.
   6.2. goto 4.
7. return best //when out of time, return the best solution found so far.
```

It is [anytime algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm), meaning it will get a better result as you give it more time to run, and eventually [at time infinity] it will find the optimal result.

Comment: Of course you can use any optimizer that doesn't depend on gradient instead of SAHC (simulated annealing, genetic algorithms, ...)